# How to disable mousewheel events in combobox?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Considering this code:

```
global value
ttk::combobox .cb -values {1 2 3 4 5} -textvariable value
pack .cb
```

When the mouse focus on the combobox widget, scrolling the mouse wheel will change the value. How do I disable the mouse wheel events?

Answer (score 0):

The scroll-wheel behaviour of a Ttk combobox widget is decided by its class binding to the `<MouseWheel>` event. To override this for single widget (we *do not* recommend changing it for all combobox widgets!) we need to add the following binding:

```
bind .cb <MouseWheel> break
```

Doing a `break` in a binding stops processing of the event in later bindtags, *particularly including the class binding* though there are potentially others. (Widgets' default bindtags are the one for the widget, which has the same name as the widget, the one for the widget's class, the one for the widget's toplevel — designed to support hotkeys — and `all` for global bindings, which is occasionally useful but usually not.)

Comment: I've tried but got error message: bad event type or keysym "ScrollWheel"

Comment: @Jimmy: try MouseWheel instead.